# Custom Validation not working with Ajax MVC Call

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, customvalidator

On the click of a button i want to sumbit a form if another form, in the same page (not a ligthbox) is valid. That validation is a Custom Validation I created and is working fine.
This is the code in the view

```
$("#btnSave").click(function (e) {

            if ($("#GeneralButtonFrm").valid()) {

                $("#ButtonFrm").submit();

            } else {
                //Error Message
            } });
```

The problem is that the submit action is executing without waiting for the response of the custom validation which return false.

Any idea why this is happening?

Note: I said I am not using a ligthbox rendering a partial becouse in that case the solution would be jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#form');

Thanks

Comment: If GeneralButtonFrm was rendered using ajax you MUST use jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse, or is it the custom validator that uses ajax? validator that uses ajax are a bit tricky you need to return false that they are not valid then when you get answer from server you need to set a flag if the value was valid, then revalidate form and return true or false depending on flag.. I hope i was clear :D

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. What do you mean with "return false when not valid"? and how/where can i get the answer from the server?

Comment: Just to get everything straight, you have a custom rule thats tries to validate using ajax?

Comment: Yes, i am using the custom validation of mvc 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

You are still very vague, in your question. But i think what you want is to call ajax and do a serverside validation. If so, the problem is that your validation will return before ajax request since the ajax request is async.. Do this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery.validator.addMethod("ajaxCustom", function (value, element) {
                var wrap = $(element);
                var url = wrap.data("customAjaxUrl");
                var result;

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: url,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                       result  = data.valid;
                    },
                    data: { value: value, id: element.id },
                    async: false
                });

                return this.optional(element) || result;

            }, "Ajax");

            $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool('ajaxCustom');
            </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .input-validation-error {
                background: red;
            }

        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <form action="/">
            <input data-val-ajaxCustom="Tuckel" data-val="true" data-val-required="Its required" data-custom-ajax-url="validate.html" />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```